# Error creating scalar function "Invalid Object Name dbo.fnMyFunctionName'"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I tried creating a new scalar function. The function gets created and I see it in the list of scalar functions.

When I try to modify function, function name is underlined in red and the mouseover text says

> *Invalid Object Name 'dbo.fnGetXName'*

If I write a query and try to ref any function, intellisense shows no functions after typing `dbo.`. It doesn't seem to matter what I name the new function, the same issue arises

Comment: Check scheme in which you create a function of yours. It might end up in `sys.` scheme, for example.

Comment: It may be intellisense error sometime. As intellisense don't work consistently always in Management studio for me too sometime.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try refreshing the Intlisense cache.

Hit crtl+shft+R

From [SQL Server Management Studio Keyboard Shortcuts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx)

> Refresh local cache

Or under

> EDIT->IntelliSense->Refresh Local Cache

Comment: Added to favorites