# Error RUNNING scalar function “Invalid Object Name TestFunction”

Tags: sql-server, functions

My problem is similar to [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/37328/63237), but with a further twist: I can't call the function without getting an error.

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 3, Line 5
Invalid object name 'TestFunction'.
```

I can live with the IntelliSense not working... but I hope I can at least get the function to run. (I have the correct database selected.)

The code is very simple:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TestFunction()
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @qty INT
  SELECT @qty = 1
  RETURN @qty
END
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TestFunction()
```

What's the problem here? Do I have to do something special to get scalar functions to work? My table-valued functions are running fine.

Comment: Now how on earth is someone supposed to improve community contributions when all people can be bothered to do is throw a drive-by downvote out the window without troubling to explain their intent. This is a poor state of affairs. Shame on those cowards who will downvote only, withholding constructive criticism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was calling the function incorrectly.

Here's the proper syntax:

```
SELECT [dbo].[TestFunction]()
```